# How do I set TomEE for enterprise project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, apache-tomee

I attached TomEE++ as `Apache Tomcat` server and it works just perfect for a `Java Web` projects in *NetBeans*.[image]

But when I create `enterprise` project, I have no option to set `TomEE++` for it. Netbeans wants me to add `GlassFish` or `Jboss` as a Server.

[image]

Does that mean Netbeans still treats any Tomcat Server as only web container without enterprise support?

> > Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (Build 201306052037)

Comment: Probably you get better answers on Netbeans forums.

Comment: I asked them too. http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=56175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this answer is about two years later, but TomEE is now supported by NB v8. I post this link so any one also finding your question has an updated response.

See [TomEE and Netbeans](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-netbeans.html)

Answer (score 2):

[I've got an answer on NetBeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=56175&sid=6d305e4018dfb244d740ceae6cbc339d):

> Posted: Thu Aug 01, 2013 12:06 am
>
> NetBeans does not currently support TomEE